# How to read a image url in google appengine using java

Tags: google-app-engine, javax.imageio

The ImageIO is not in the whitelist of GAE.
How to read a image(JPG,PNG) from url as ImageBuffer without using ImageIO?

Comment: @systempuntoout No, because they want to manipulate the image, not just store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the url stream and  create a bytearray using the [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from apache commons.

```
URL url = new URL(this.url);
InputStream input = url.openStream();
byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(input)
```

<sup>Note:

`toByteArray` method buffers the input internally, so there is no need to use a `BufferedInputStream`.</sup>

**EDIT:**
BufferedImage is listed as not supported on AppEngine; that means that you CAN'T use that third party library on Google App Engine.

Comment: I see, but the third party API is using the ImageBuffer as the parameter. How to fix the problem?

Comment: Which Java library has ImageBuffer? Do you mean `BufferedImage`?

Comment: Yes!How to handle such issue?Thanks!

Comment: @John sorry but you can't do much with that third party library. Maybe it offers something that can be obtained also with the Google App Engine Image library.

Answer (score 6):

just use this Google App Engine built in API

```
byte[] b = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch( url ).getContent();
```

No third party library required !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read the image content, not only its byte stream, the library https://github.com/pascalleclercq/appengine-awt does the job very well, just replace the usual imports with:

```
import com.google.code.appengine.awt.image.BufferedImage
import com.google.code.appengine.imageio.ImageIO
```

The library is published at Maven at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.appengine-awt/appengine-awt/1.0.0