# Alternative to ImageIO class on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, zxing, google-glass

My Working example in normal J2EE application:

```
// decode the image 
    InputStream inputStream = new File("/images/test.png");
    BufferedImage barCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
    if (barCodeBufferedImage != null) {
        LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(barCodeBufferedImage);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Result results = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
        //System.out.println("Decoded barcode image :: "+results.getText());
        return results.getText();
    }
```

Same I want to achieve in GAE. But it blocks the ImageIO class and BufferedImage class.
Can anybody tell me alternative of ImageIO class on GAE??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a image url in google appengine using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856552/how-to-read-a-image-url-in-google-appengine-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine has a limited set of Image APIs which documentation you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/).

The basic operations include cropping, rotation, flipping, resizing and some color manipulation.

The static [makeImage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesServiceFactory#makeImage%28byte%5b%5d%29) method will build an Image from a byte array.